# Tags inside <button> clickable even if button is disabled - Webkit only

Tags: jquery, button, webkit, tags

Here is a fiddle to prove my point. When I use `$(document).on("click"....)`, I can still click on tags inside a disabled button. This behavior does not occur with `$("button").click(`..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QGMTV/)

Can someone explain this discrepancy? Is it a bug, or a feature of jQuery?

Edit: The workaround I have come up with:

```
$(document).on("click", "button > *", function() {
    if ( $(this).parent().is(":disabled") )
    {    
        return false;
    }
});
```

​

Comment: It does not fire for me, I'm using firefox 14.1/mac.

Comment: What u try to expalin and by the way it does not fire for me, I'm using firefox 14.1

Comment: Question is: why does the document.on fire but the button.click doesn't. It's a good question

Comment: Sorry, using latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I just tested it in FF and IE8/9. All working correctly. This seems to be a webkit only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been a bug with JQuery 1.7.1. If you move to 1.7.2 or 1.8, it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior results from the element to which you're applying the event.  In the first example, you're binding the event to document.  In the second example, you're binding the event to the button.  This is pure speculation because I haven't looked at the jQuery source code to actually see what's executed when you use `$().on()`, but I think that the selectors are resolved after the event fires.

For example, `document` picks up the click event, resolves the selectors to test which it should apply to, and then executes the function.  In the second scenario, the selectors are resolved first before the click event is bound.

Comment: It actually only occurs in webkit - leading me to believe a problem with webkit instead of JQuery.